# How to alter the scale of x-axis and y-axis in Python

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

We're working with Python, and we retrieve data from our MySQL database. We need to create a seriel plot, and we use matplotlib to do so. Unfortunately we dont have success on creating the plot.

The plot should look like this:

[image]

Unfortunately our plot looks like this:

[image]

We've discussed that this might be fixed if we alter x-axis and y-axis. Instead of having tons of timestamp with time in x-axis (which is probably the reason why it's blurred in black), we can set up dates in days, as we have shown in the first image.

**CODE**

Code is picking first timestamp, and then set up a range of one week, so we only take data from first timestamp and 1 week ahead.

```
engine = create_engine("mysql://root:DTULab@123@localhost/Afgangsprojekt")
conn = engine.connect()

firstTime = pd.read_sql('SELECT timestamp FROM Raw_Data WHERE topic = "lpn1"', conn).astype(str).values[:,0].tolist()

t = (pd.to_datetime(firstTime[0]) + datetime.timedelta(weeks=1))

time = pd.read_sql(f'SELECT timestamp FROM Raw_Data WHERE topic = "lpn1" AND timestamp < "{t}"', conn).astype(str).values[:,0].tolist()
temp = pd.read_sql(f'SELECT temperature FROM Raw_Data WHERE topic = "lpn1" AND timestamp < "{t}"', conn).astype(str).values[:,0].tolist()

# plot
plt.plot(time, temp)
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.savefig('foo.png')
```

Comment: You are plotting strings. Make sure to plot numbers and/or dates instead.

Comment: damn.. how did i miss that. Thanks for that!